# Can the right ctrl key be turned off in Windows 10?

Tags: keyboard, key, ctrl

At some point in the past my right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key stopped working and now I cannot turn it back on again. I have an HP USB keyboard. I'm using Windows 10. I suspect it happened after I installed VMWare Workstation and opted for the Enhanced Keyboard Driver, but I can't say for sure. Here's what I tried so far:

- Uninstalled VMWare and restarted, but it didn't solve the problem.
- Rebooted Windows in safe mode, the problem persists there, too.
- Uninstalled the keyboard driver and rebooted, no change.
- Connected another USB keyboard, the problem is still there, so I think it must be software.
- Turned on the on-screen keyboard and press the left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, both <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys light up in the display. When I press the right one, nothing happens.